# Android Don't calls onActivityResult with DialogFragment

Tags: android, onactivityresult, dialogfragment

I've got a code that starts intent to take picture from camera

```
Intent pictureActionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, PhotoUtility.CAMERA_PICTURE);
```

And after picture is taking back it should calls `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if (requestCode == PhotoUtility.CAMERA_PICTURE) {
        File f = PhotoUtility.saveFromCamera(data, picIV);
        imagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    } else if (requestCode == PhotoUtility.GALLERY_PICTURE) {
        File f = PhotoUtility.saveFromGallery(data, getActivity(), picIV);
        imagePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

With simple `Fragment` it works fine, but if I use `DialogFragment` `onActivityResult` is not calling. How can solve this problem using `DialogFragment`?

Comment: Put complete code, including your dialog fragemet and fragment, have you implemented captrue image logic yourself, or are your using inbuilt apps for that??

Comment: Did you mean you are calling the intent from the dialog fragment and its not working?

Comment: DialogFragment is no different than its base Fragnent class,  it works exactly the same